# Why is the left table not being preserved in a left outer Join?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I wrote this query against a redshift database

```
with wt_id(id) as (select cast(11646722011 as bigint))
  select 
    w.id, 
    nullif(
      trim(
        regexp_replace(
          json_extract_path_text(bn.foo, 'foo-id'), '\\["(.*)"\\]', '$$1'
        )
      ), '') as foo-id
  from wt_id w left outer join foo bn on w.id = bn.fid
  where bn.day='2019-12-03' 
  limit 1;
```

This query returns an empty result set. But how is this possible? because I did a left out join, I should get 1 row where id is 11646722011 and the foo-id can be null if there was no match on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause is converting the outer join to an inner join because `NULL` fails the `WHERE` condition.

Conditions on the *second* table in a `left join` should be in the on clause.  So you want:

```
from wt_id w left outer join
     foo bn
     on w.id = bn.fid and bn.day = '2019-12-03'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` clause has made your data loss. This is not the case about left join allows unmatched rows but about no data on that specific day after left join. So, you should replace `where` with `and`.

If we see the order of execution the where gets applied after the join as above. Hence, even if the rows gets null it gets removed if the other condition gets true as your day.